# picklist chose based on profile

Tags: picklist

I have 5 picklist values A,B,C,D,E; and 3 profiles P1, P2, P3. P1 Can see only A, B and P2 can see only E and p3 can see C,D. How could I do that any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- P1 Can see only A, B
- P2 can see only E
- p3 can see C,D.

So create 3 recordtypes and assign respective picklist values to that recordtypes.

Finally assign recordtypes to each profiles.

Comment: If my answer solves your purpose then please accept this so others may find this useful